# Print pattern on a string with special character

Tags: sed

How to print only string `figure` with the following line :

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
```

I tried :

```
firstLine='\begin{figure}[h!]'
echo $firstLine | sed -n 's/\\begin{\(.*\)}/\1/p'
```

but returns :

`figure[h!]` instead of `figure`

It seems that issue comes from `[]` or `!` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
firstLine='\begin{figure}[h!]'
echo "$firstLine" | sed 's/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
figure
```

With your code (add `.*`):

```
echo $firstLine | sed -n 's/\\begin{\(.*\)}.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that \(.*\) was the pattern printed by \1/p but it also include the rest of end line

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/' file
```

This assumes there is only one `{...}` expression and one line.

A more rigorous solution would be:

```
sed -n 's/.*\\begin{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/p' file
```

However nothing would be output if no match was found.